# Propensity score matching in R (problem with code)

Tags: r

I am a complete beginner at R and don't have much time to complete this analysis.

I need to run propensity score matching. I am using RStudio and have

- Uploaded my dataset which is called 'R' and was saved on my desktop
- Installed and loaded package `Matchit`

My dataset has the following headings:

- `BA` (my grouping variable of which someone is either on BA or not, 0=off, 1=on),
- Then `age`, `sex`, `timesincediagnosis`, `TVS`, and `tscore` which are my matching variables.

I have adapted the following code which I have found online

```
m.nn <- matchit(ba ~ age + sex + timesincediagnosis + TVS + tscore, 
    data = R, method= " nearest", ratio = 1)
summary(m.nn)
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
Error in summary(m.nn) : object 'm.nn' not found

Error in matchit(ba ~ age + sex + timesincediagnosis + TVS + tscore, 
    data = R,  :    nearestnot supported.
```

I would really appreciate any help with why I am getting the errors or how I can change my code.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Also it looks like you have an extra space in your method name. What if you tried `method= "nearest"` (without the leading space).

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to @MrFlick for noticing this, but the problem is that `" nearest"` is not an acceptable value to be passed to `method`. What you want is `"nearest"` (without the leading space in the string). (Note that the default method is nearest neighbor matching, so you can omit the `method` argument entirely if this is what you want to do.)

The error print first (`Error in summary(m.nn) : object 'm.nn' not found`) occurs because R didn't create the `m.nn` object because of the other error.